# HTML align div to the center

Tags: html, css, styles

I have a div with 3 images :

```css
.main_block {
  width: 800px;
}

.main_block: before, .main_block: after {
  overflow: hidden;
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.main_block: after {
  clear: both;
}

.inner_block {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 20px
}

.inner_block img {
  height: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="main_block">
  <div class="inner_block">
    <img src="img/features/1.png"/>
  </div>

  <div class="inner_block">
    <img src="img/features/2.png"/>
  </div>  
  <div class="inner_block">
    <img src="img/features/3.png"/>
  </div>   
</div>
```

And it allways align to the left of the page, i tried to add position relative to the main div but it's still align to the left

Comment: Did you try margin:0 auto to main_block ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Horizontally center a div in a div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/horizontally-center-a-div-in-a-div)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use flexbox for this:

`display:flex` is the key

here is the [code](https://jsfiddle.net/MaciejWojcik/bk1wdmpb/)

```css
.main_block {
    width: 100%;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:space-between;
}

.inner_block {
    display: inline-block;    
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="main_block">
        <div class="inner_block">
                <img src="http://html5doctor.com/wp-content/themes/html5doctor2/images/HTML5_Badge_64.png"/>
            </div>

            <div class="inner_block">
                <img src="http://html5doctor.com/wp-content/themes/html5doctor2/images/HTML5_Badge_64.png"/>
            </div>  
        <div class="inner_block">
                <img src="http://html5doctor.com/wp-content/themes/html5doctor2/images/HTML5_Badge_64.png"/>
            </div>   
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just add a `text-align:center;` to the main div, and remove `float: left;` on the inner divs.

```css
.main_block {
  width: 800px;
  text-align:center;
}

.main_block: before, .main_block: after {
  overflow: hidden;
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.main_block: after {
  clear: both;
}

.inner_block {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 20px
}

.inner_block img {
  height: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="main_block">
  <div class="inner_block">
    <img src="img/features/1.png"/>
  </div>

  <div class="inner_block">
    <img src="img/features/2.png"/>
  </div>  
  <div class="inner_block">
    <img src="img/features/3.png"/>
  </div>   
</div>
```

Is it what you want ?

Answer (score -1):

It is because of the `float` property in the `.inner-block` class. You can remove it and add `<center></center>` selector in the html file. Code snippet below:

```css
.main_block {
    width: 800px;
}

.main_block: before, .main_block: after {
    overflow: hidden;
    content: "";
    display: table;
}

.main_block: after {
    clear: both;
}

.inner_block {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 20px
}

.inner_block img {
    height: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="main_block">
      <center>
        <div class="inner_block">
                <img src="http://blinklist.com/files/logos/lastpass-logo.gif"/>
            </div>

            <div class="inner_block">
                <img src="http://blinklist.com/files/logos/lastpass-logo.gif"/>
            </div>  
        <div class="inner_block">
                <img src="http://blinklist.com/files/logos/lastpass-logo.gif"/>
            </div>   
            </center>
    </div>
```

Comment: It's bad practice to use <center> tag in html

Answer (score -1):

I think it works

.main_block {
        width: 800px;
        margin: 0 auto
    }